# How to make the output axis of hingejoint with rotational motor not affected by physics?

Tags: simulation, webots

I want the rotational motors be affected only by my controller, not by the physics of the world. The problem is shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/KoJxHR5aGYI). How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the environment is applying some forces and torques on your motor and the motor cannot hold its position because it is not strong enough. To fix this problem, you should simply increase the strength of the motor. For a [RotationalMotor](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/rotationalmotor), increasing the `maxTorque` value should resolve the problem.

You should also ensure that you didn't override this value with a lower value using [wb_motor_set_available_torque](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#wb_motor_set_available_torque) or [wb_motor_set_torque](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#wb_motor_set_torque). That means that you should not perform [torque/force control](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#force-and-torque-control), but either [position control](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#position-control) or [velocity control](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/motor#velocity-control) (so that you don't limit the motor torque).

For a [LinearMotor](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/linearmotor), the same applies with the `force` settings of the motor instead of `torque`. But I believe that in your case, you only have rotational motors.

Comment: oh that makes sense, thank you very much! I also experimented with turning the dampingConsant high in Hingejoint parameters, is this also a viable solution? somehow it also works

Comment: Yes, increasing the value of `dampingConstant` will have basically a similar effect. However, it will have a different impact on the dynamics of your simulation.

Comment: Hi Oliver, please read the meta answer https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1485/37 and the question associated with it. Your teams has been flagged as a possible voting ring, and we would like to help avoid that in the future.